# How to select immediate preceding sibling

Tags: xpath

How to select previous `tr`?
[image]

I am trying

```
//tr[@id='20-covers']/preceding-sibling::tr
```

But it select 1st `tr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually your XPath returns the *list of preceding `tr` siblings* while the tool you're using might select the *first element from this list*

You might need to explicitly specify the index of element (`[1]`) to get *immediate preceding `tr`*:

```
//tr[@id='20-covers']/preceding-sibling::tr[1]
```